# Should I use NuGet or DLL reference?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a project in C# for usiversity. I want to use SQLite in it, but how should I include it, knowing that I will have to give my teacher the full VS2015 project folder ?

I also use 2 computers with github to transfer the sources.

Since I don't know a lot about NuGet or external library (DLL) reference with Visual Studio, i have no idea what I should use.

Will NuGet install SQLite in the project folder, or should I choose the DLL (from [here](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)), and put it in the project folder ?

Also on a side question, should I ignore the SQLite files when commiting ?

Comment: NuGet with package restore turned on would solve your problem.

Comment: What does "package restore" do ? I don't actually have a "problem", more like a dilemma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use NuGet, and yes you should add your packages folder to the `.gitignore`.

Comment: So when someone opens the project in VS, it will automatically download the NuGet package before / while generation the solution ?

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for replying so quickly.

Comment: No problem. If this helped, please mark as answered.

Comment: Yes of course. I wanted to do so, but I have to wait 8 more minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely suggest NuGet as well. NuGet can be set to automatically restore the files when a new person builds. (Package Restore, by the way, just means that NuGet will download the necessary files automatically). That way you don't have to pass around DLLs. It also helps make sure that everyone's on the correct version.

In general, it's considered a bad practice to check executable code into source control if you can avoid it. Doing so can make it much more difficult to track history and version differences, for example.